# GUI, two accounts to use different languages

Tags: 14.04, gui, language-support

Two accounts are set-up, one normal user, one administrative. Ubuntu gui should be in English if administrator is logged in and for all man pages, but it should be in user's language every time the normal user is logged in. How to achieve this ?

Whole GUI, means OS and all software applications are addressed.

Comment: What when both are logged in?

Comment: Exact the same applies. The admin will have GUI in English, the user will have Ubuntu GUI in his/her language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Language Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language.html) when logged in as the admin user. Make sure all languages you need are installed, select English and apply system wide. Then, when logged in as the standard user, use Language Support to switch to the desired language.